# if reponse is true then clear form after receiving true response

Tags: javascript

I've a form with validate, currently it's working with no issue. My problem is related to clear form after true response. It's related to Javascript code.

This is my code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
          var url = $(".url").val();
      // start sign up functionality
          $(".signupbtn").on('click',function(){
          $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>account/signup",$("#headersignupform").serialize(), function(response){
          if($.trim(response) == 'true'){
                          $('#headersignupform')[0].reset();
                          $(".resultsignup").html(response).delay(5000).fadeIn("slow");
          }else{
          $(".resultsignup").html(response); } }); });
      // end signup functionality
      })
       $(function() {
          $('.signupbtn').click(function() {
              $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: $(".toppage").offset().top - 100
              }, 'slow');
          });
      })
    </script>
```

I have used `clearForm();` and `$('#headersignupform')[0].reset();` but it doesn't work after true response. I don't know what I should use to clear form after true response.

I highly appreciate if you help me for this.

Comment: Is that section of code even getting executed? Have you debugged it to determine that?

Comment: I don't see any `clearForm()`?

Comment: I mean I used clearForm(); instead of reset(); but it doesn't work. what should I use to clear form ?